# Is there a way to display 3d models in a react native project without expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, react-native-cli

I'm trying to display 3d models in a react native project without using expo .
All I can find is examples using expo for react native .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not a problem that I'm facing in my code I'm looking if anyone knows a way to implement showing a 3d model in a react native cli project all I can find is expo examples

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes you can.

Long answer: You'll need quite a few libraries and some of the libraries are from EXPO. You can use expo libraries in pure react native without using expo CLI.

Here is working code example to load 3D model type .obj with orbit control.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { ExpoWebGLRenderingContext, GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { resolveAsync } from 'expo-asset-utils';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { decode } from 'base64-arraybuffer';
import { Renderer, TextureLoader, loadObjAsync, loadTextureAsync } from 'expo-three';
import OrbitControlsView from 'expo-three-orbit-controls';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset'
import {
  AmbientLight,
  BoxGeometry,
  Fog,
  GridHelper,
  Mesh,
  MeshStandardMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  PointLight,
  Scene,
  SpotLight,
  Camera,
} from 'three';

const ThreeD = () => {
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState<Camera | null>(null);

  let timeout;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);

  const onContextCreate = async (gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
    const { drawingBufferWidth: width, drawingBufferHeight: height } = gl;
    const sceneColor = 0x6ad6f0;

    // Create a WebGLRenderer without a DOM element
    const renderer = new Renderer({ gl });
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.setClearColor(sceneColor);

    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 0.01, 1000);
    camera.position.set(2, 5, 5);
    setCamera(camera);

    const scene = new Scene();
    scene.fog = new Fog(sceneColor, 1, 10000);
    scene.add(new GridHelper(10, 10));

    const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0xB1B1B1, 1.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const spotLight = new SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
    spotLight.position.set(0, 200, 200);
    spotLight.lookAt(scene.position);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    const texture = await loadTextureAsync({
      asset: require('../assets/3D/model_texture.xpng'),
    });

    const obj = await loadObjAsync({
      asset: require('../assets/3D/model.obj')
    });
    obj.traverse(function(object) {
      if (object instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        object.material.map = texture;
      }
    });

    scene.add(obj);

    camera.lookAt(obj.position);

    function update() {
      obj.rotation.y = 0;
      obj.rotation.x = 0;
    }

    // Setup an animation loop
    const render = () => {
      timeout = requestAnimationFrame(render);
      update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);

      gl.endFrameEXP();
    };
    render();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <OrbitControlsView style={{ flex: 1 }} camera={camera}>
        <GLView style={{ flex: 1 }} onContextCreate={onContextCreate} key="d" />
      </OrbitControlsView>
    </View>

  );
};

export default ThreeD;
```

This has already been discussed on GitHub. So, I won't go into much detail.

You can go to [this comment](https://github.com/expo/expo-three/issues/151#issuecomment-904532776) to read more.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement 3D Models ( gltf, glb, obj...) in react-native using Three.js

Example:
https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'

function Box(props) {
  // This reference gives us direct access to the THREE.Mesh object
  const ref = useRef()
  // Hold state for hovered and clicked events
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false)
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false)
  // Subscribe this component to the render-loop, rotate the mesh every frame
  useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.rotation.x += 0.01))
  // Return the view, these are regular Threejs elements expressed in JSX
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      scale={clicked ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={(event) => click(!clicked)}
      onPointerOver={(event) => hover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(event) => hover(false)}>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <Canvas>
    <ambientLight />
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />
    <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
  </Canvas>,
)
```

You can find complete documentation over here: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

**NOTE: This is not my code I just pasted it over here for reference.**